# Refreshing Tabbed View Pages in Xamarin.Forms UWP/Windows 8.1

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created sample Xamarin forms application which contains 2 tabs. When user logins, then I am navigating the user to tabs view by setting the tab view to MainPage property.

Whenever I am navigating between the tabs,  want to move selected list item from one page to another page and show on the second page.

Whenever I am selecting row from the list and navigating to another page either by clicking the tab or swiping to right, the page doesn't show the value. I tried to refresh the page by calling OnAppearing event but that is not called when I navigate.